# Dealing with out of phasors

Tags: trigonometry

Year 2 engineering mature student 
I have a question

A voltage wave form

$$v=30\sin(wt)+7.5\sin\left(3w+\frac\pi4\right)$$

A current wave form

$$I=\sin(wt)=0.15\sin\left(3wt-\frac\pi{12}\right)$$

I have been asked to work out the voltage rms and current rms which I have, I have the total power which was v x 1

I need to work out the true power but I am struggling on how to deal with the

$(3wt-\frac\pi{12})$ and $(3w+\frac\pi4)$

do I take the angles away from each other?
A example on how to deal with these would be very much appreciated

any help would be great

Thanks

Krissie

Comment: *"do I take the angles away from each other?"* Which angles do you mean?

Comment: By the way, I've formatted your post to use MathJax. Someone can give you a link explaining how to do this yourself in the future.

Comment: Do you know how to represent sine as the real part of a complex exponential function?

Comment: Are you missing a $t$ in the second part of $v$?

Comment: The equation for the current does not make sense. Is there a + instead of =?